# c++ fizzbuzz switch statement?

Tags: c++, for-loop, switch-statement, fizzbuzz

I'm trying to see if I can make a fizzbuzz c++ switch statement. I'm getting an error saying i is not usable in a const expression. Does that mean I can't make this thing work? Or is there a work around? Here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    for(int = 1; 1 <= 100; i++){
        switch(true){

            case(i % 3 == 0 & i % 5 == 0):
                cout << "fizzbuzz" << endl;
                break;

            case(i % 3 == 0):
                cout << "fizz" << endl;
                break;

            case(i % 5 == 0):
                cout << "fizz" << endl;
                break;
            default:
                cout << i << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you nee to revisit how `switch` works: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch

Comment: You cannot use `switch` / `case` that way. Use `if` , `else if` instead.

Comment: I think you need to read a good C++ book first. There's a lot of errors in this code

Comment: [List of good C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/253056).

Comment: Only constants are alowed for `case`s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to use switch/case then you could do it like this:

```
switch (i % 15)
{
    case 0 : cout << "fizzbuzz\n"; break;

    case 5:
    case 10: cout << "buzz\n"; break;

    case 3:
    case 6:
    case 9:
    case 12: cout << "fizz\n"; break;

    default: cout << i << "\n"; break;;
}
```

Comment: Well,  the `default` case, should, be `cout << i << endl;`, as is in the question.

Comment: Thanks man, I get what i was doing wrong by what you showed. Interesting how it works, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of fundamental problems with how you're using switch/case.

The expected way to use it is to have the `switch` refer to a variable or expression, then the `case` sections refer to constant values.

Instead what you're doing is `switch(true)` which doesn't make any sense, even though it compiles. It's equivalent to `switch(1)`. So in that case only `case 1:` would ever apply.

You cannot use expressions for `case`. These must be constant integer values. So for example you can either plain integers `case 0:`, or also commonly pre-processor defines `case FIZZBUZZ:`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, several times, you cannot always use a `switch()` statement like a `if` statement and there are several other issues with your code.  I am not going to give you the right answer as I don't believe that will help you the most.

**Here are some notes:**
1) Instead of a switch you should use `if`, `else if`, and `else` statements.
2) In C++ a `and` is expressed as `&&` not `&`
3) A `for` loop is declared like `for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)`

You should watch/read some simple tutorials on how to code C++ as it is important you understand these basics.

Comment: I know how to with an if else statement, was just trying to get creative

Comment: @DanielArchuleta Use what works best for what you are trying to do.  A switch isn't creative if you are "trying" to use it.

Comment: All I'm trying to see was if it was possible to use a switch statement, for fun you know, i'm not using it for anything.